# Dump all defined properties in Ant script

Tags: ant

I have an Ant script that imports several external scripts and property files which were not written by me. (It's a project that was automatically generated by the Android SDK, but that shouldn't matter.) I added a custom target to the script, but I'd like to do a better job of integrating it with the stuff that's already there. What I need is a comprehensive list of the global properties that are defined at a particular point in script execution. Is there any way to do that with Ant?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [Echoproperties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) task.

Comment: note that if you need to access environment variables, and they aren't in your dump, you can add them by doing this: `<property environment="env"/>`. Then they'll be available by using the `env` prefix. e.g. `${env.PATH}`. Picked up [from here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=476788)